# C#: How to catch exception in MySql rollback

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to connect to a MySql database. Some long queries are timing out and then my application crashes. In event viewer I see this exception:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ExecutePacket(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendQuery(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.SendQuery(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.ExecuteNext()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.ExecuteNext()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Rollback()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransactionScope.Rollback(System.Transactions.SinglePhaseEnlistment)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPromotableTransaction.System.Transactions.IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification.Rollback(System.Transactions.SinglePhaseEnlistment)
at System.Transactions.DurableEnlistmentAborting.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalEnlistment)
at System.Transactions.DurableEnlistmentActive.InternalAborted(System.Transactions.InternalEnlistment)
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction)
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateActive.Rollback(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction, System.Exception)
at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Timeout(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction)
at System.Transactions.Bucket.TimeoutTransactions()
at System.Transactions.BucketSet.TimeoutTransactions()
at System.Transactions.TransactionTable.ThreadTimer(System.Object)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

So it looks like it's trying to do a rollback when the command timeouts. During this rollback something seems to fail.

The try-catch around the NonQuery is not catching this exception. My code:

```
                try
                {
                    using (MyDB db = new MyDB())
                    {
                        db.Database.CommandTimeout = 240;
                        using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
                        {
                            db.MyTable.AddRange(dataToSave);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            tran.Complete();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    monitor.OnException(ex);
                }
```

So how can I catch the rollback exception? I don't want my application to crash completely when this happens.

Comment: Can you try executing those queries directly (console, phpmyadmin or what have you) to ensure it's the length or the style of your queries that is causing this? `NullReferenceException` seems odd imho.

Comment: The queries work as expected when executed directly. In this piece of code, they work correclty 99% of the time. But sometimes, when the MySql server is very busy it seems to timeout, after which my application crashes.

Comment: I've found this MySql bug, but it doesn't seem fixed: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61094

Comment: I hope there is a workaround though, as this bug is already present 4 years apparently...

Answer (score 0):

Not answering direct problem - but it doesn't look that you use TransactionScope correctly. It looks that purpose of TransactionScope is one level above regular database transactions. E.g. see example in [.net docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NotExistJustToMakeTheAElementVisible)    
You probably better to use plain regular database transactions to avoid similar issues.