# What may be the cause for an intermittent Object reference not set error on a windows forms application with MySql database backend?

Tags: mysql, codefluent

I have a Windows Forms application, where the underlying database is MySql.
Versions are as follows:

MySql Server v5.6

MySql Connector for .NET v6.5.4

Windows 7 64-bit

I get the error with the stack trace below, in an **INTERMITTENT** pattern. It happens each time in different parts of the application. Sometimes it takes a couple of days to happen, sometimes I get this 3 or 4 times a day.

On the specific occurrence where I collected this stack trace error, having the dialog box with the error still showing on the screen, I managed to open a second instance of my windows forms application, **in parallel**, only to notice that this second instance was working flawlessly. This is the pattern (or lack of it): whenever this issue shows up, just closing and restarting the application, or even opening another instance in parallel, is enough to restore database access. If I don't exit the application when this failure happens, all subsequent attempts the application makes to access MySql database fail, no matter what. The error dialog box option to *"ignore this error and attempt to continue"* allows me to conclude that it seems like MySql database backend and that particular instance of the windows forms application got "disconnected", even to subsequent attempts.

I understand that the stack trace information is a chain of events with the most recent at the top, so is it correct to assume that the failing point is at this event?

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ExecutePacket(MySqlPacket packetToExecute)
```

I tried researching on this specific "MySql NativeDriver.ExecutePacket.. Object reference not set" everywhere, I could only get reports of people having this on seemingly unrelated issues with varying execution contexts, many of them even reporting as MySql bugs submitted to be fixed.

Anyway, I would appreciate any insight on the issue at hand, even suggestions on how to maybe properly debugging and even tuning MySql's configuration properties. I am open to any ideas.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
    just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ExecutePacket(MySqlPacket packetToExecute)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendQuery(MySqlPacket queryPacket)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.SendQuery(MySqlPacket p)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.ExecuteNext()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.ExecuteNext()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.MySQL.CodeFluentMySQLPersistenceHook.SetForeignKeyChecks(MySqlConnection mySqlConnection)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.MySQL.CodeFluentMySQLPersistenceHook.AfterOpenConnection(IDbConnection connection)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.OpenConnection()
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.InternalExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean firstTry)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.ExecuteReader()
   at S5T.AssociadoSetorCob.LoadBypCodigo(Int32 pCodigo)
   at S5TWin.FormGeraArqBanco.cmbSetor_MontaPesquisaTextBox(String& desc)
   at S5TWin.ComboCF.txtCodigo_Leave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLeave(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyLeave()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1022 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
```

Long list of loaded assemblies, cut short for brevity

Comment: NullReferenceException in a code that belongs to the MyqlClient's NativeDriver class looks like a bug in that client/class (maybe already reported: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61094). You should try to upgrade to 6.9.8 or report this error to MySQL dev guys.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, @SimonMourier, I reported this error to MySql bug dev guys. The approach of upgrading to 6.9.8 raised OTHER ISSUE: every access is slow, very slow. Just by switching connectors and nothing else... That's why for now I reverted it all back 6.5.4, which gives me a "sweet spot" on this responsiveness issue...

Comment: Looking at MySQL forums (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61094) and also other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094122/c-how-to-catch-exception-in-mysql-rollback), it looks like it's due to an earlier exception that does not keep things in a state like it should. So maybe it depends on things you do or things happening before that (transaction failure? etc. maybe record all errors prior to this one, with a tool such as http://getglimpse.com/). Otherwise if it's fixed in latest version, then try to find out why it's so slow...

Comment: Regarding slow responsiveness, I just posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618873/how-to-solve-low-performance-issues-with-net-mysql-connector-on-latest-versions). I'll try to investigate further if things I do, monitor the application behavior more closely.